# Replication for partitioned table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication, symmetricds

I want to replicate a partitioned table in PostgreSQL using SymmetricDS. Do I have to configure sym_trigger for individual partitioning table or just the partitioned table?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to setup a SymmetricDS trigger just like any other table configured for replication.  The PostgreSQL database will take care of what triggers are cloned/created on each partition.

Comment: yes. that approach works for me. Thanks